# python regex find text with digits

Tags: python, regex

I have text like:

```
sometext...one=1290...sometext...two=12985...sometext...three=1233...
```

How can I find `one=1290` and `two=12985` but not three or four or five? There are can be from 4 to 5 digits after `=`. I tried this:

```
import re
pattern = r"(one|two)+=+(\d{4,5})+\D"
found = re.findall(pattern, sometext, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(found)
```

It gives me results like: `[('one', '1290')]`. 
If i use `pattern = r"((one|two)+=+(\d{4,5})+\D)"` it gives me `[('one=1290', 'one', '1290')]`. How can I get just `one=1290`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. You need to use  a single capture group (or none for that matter):

```
((?:one|two)+=+\d{4,5})+
```

Full code:

```
import re

string = 'sometext...one=1290...sometext...two=12985...sometext...three=1233...'

pattern = r"((?:one|two)+=+\d{4,5})+"
found = re.findall(pattern, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(found)
# ['one=1290', 'two=12985']
```

Comment: Exactly this.
To summarize what the `findall()` method returns, remember the following:
When called on a regex with no groups, such as `\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d`, the method `findall()` returns a list of string matches, such as `['123-456-7890', '987-654-3210']`.
When called on a regex that has groups, such as `(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)`, the method `findall()` returns a list of tuples of strings (one string for each group), such as `[('123', '456', '7890'), ('987', '654', '3210')]`.
Here, the outermost capture group is returned to give the answer(s) you require.

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner groups non capturing: `((?:one|two)+=+(?:\d{4,5})+\D)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting results like `[('one', '1290')]` rather than `one=1290` is because you are using **capture groups**. Use:

```
r"(?:one|two)=(?:\d{4,5})(?=\D)"
```

- I have removed the additional `+` repeaters, as they were (I think?) unnecessary. You don't want to match things like `oneonetwo===1234`, right?
- Using `(?:...)` rather than `(...)` defines a **non-capture** group. This prevents the result of the capture from being returned, and you instead get the *whole* match.
- Similarly, using `(?=\D)` defines a *look-ahead* - so this is excluded from the match result.